# fgets() while loop won't break

Tags: fgets

I took out some part of the code in the while loop, but I want to break out of the fgets() while loop until it reads in a character 'q'. But the program still wants some input and it doesn't end the program. Why doesn't this method work?

```
char buffer[300];

while (fgets(buffer, 300, stdin))
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 300; i++){
       if (buffer[i] == 'q')
           break;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative to the good recommendation given by @John3136 would be to create a flag which you can use to conditionally break out of the outer loop if you hit the letter `'q'` in the inner loop.  The following code lets you keep the same general structure you had originally:

```
while (fgets(buffer, 300, stdin)) {
    bool is_break = false;
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 300; i++){
        if (buffer[i] == 'q') {
            is_break = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (is_break)
        break;
}
```

Comment: I placed the is_break = true; line on top of break; and it properly breaks out of the loop

Answer (score 0):

You've broken out of the `for` loop but not the `while` loop.
Refactor so that the while loop uses a variable rather than `fgets` directly.

```
int keep_going = fgets(buffer, 300, stdin);
while(keep_going)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 300; i++){
       if (buffer[i] == 'q')
       {
           keep_going = 0;
           break;
       }
       keep_going = fgets(buffer, 300, stdin);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer!